# Programmatically trigger the equivalent of the @click event in a list item

Tags: list, vue.js, quasar

In a list of items (in quasar a q-list) is it possible to programmatically select a particular item from the list, for example, from a button?

The problem is mainly to programmatically trigger the equivalent of the @click  event in the list item (or select event if it exists in Vue or Quasar).

In the following way it is possible to obtain the item to select, but I think that, somehow, I will have to use the 'el' of the component

```
let itemToSelect = 2;

this.item = this.itens.find( (item) => {
     return item.id === itemToSelect                          
})

console.log(this.item);
```

**EDITED**

To better illustrate what I want to achieve:
https://codepen.io/ijose/pen/vYEwazj

Comment: What does the click handler for the list items look like? Is it a function that you wrote or is it something that is handled by the library? When an item is selected, what happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually to trigger a click of a button that is rendered in the template, you put a ref on the specific button and call it like this:

template

```html
<button ref="button1" @click="alert"></button>
```

the call for example

```js
mounted() {
    this.$refs.button1.click();
  },
  methods: {
    alert(){
      alert("hello");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian A. My problem is to programmatically select an item from a list; for example, selecting item two (according to the respective id) from a list (with four or more items)

Comment: can you elaborate more on what you need to do specifying a detailed example?

Comment: Thanks Adrian A. Your solution helps me a lot to solve my problem.